# Getting just the id of a set of MongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following problem, I have already done some research in the net and here, but no solution found so far, I would be glad to receive suggestions.

Consider the code:

```
    myModel.create(array).then((justCreated)=>
{
//justCreated is the array of document just created, I can print them out and see!
})
```

My problem is: I just need their ids, on a array if possible. I could take one by one, but, *is there a better way?*

I have tried setting the second parameter to "_id" like we do with `find` or `select` like we do with `populate`, but no success. **Any suggestion?**

PS. I am using mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [post](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f) you can see that `forEach` is much slower than `map` method. So i think a better solution is the following

```
myModel.create(array)
.then(justCreated => {
    const idsArray = justCreated.map(el => el._id);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: thanks, I will take into consideration your suggest!

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your answer! I read the article, and the final part, namely "Which is better?", for my situation, it seems that `FoEach` is better: Since my dataset is big, mongoose does not allow me to save at once, as so, I need to save by parts, which means that it is not possible to return the final array at once; further, I am not chaining anything, as the article says would be preferable to `map`. Anyway. I shall consider the two options, and come back here later!

Answer (score 1):

After giving some extra thoughts, I have come up with the solution, which I am afraid regarding performace, since my dataset is pretty big, that is the reason I cannot use subdocument, I have tried, but I exceed easily the 16MB maximum limit.

```
    myModel.create(array).then((justCreated)=>
{
justCreated.ForEach((doc)=>{id.push(doc.id))
})
```

I am opened to suggestion for better ways to handle this problem but this seems to solve the problem, at least at first glance.